# Verify the following identity with prosthaphaeresis formulas

Tags: trigonometry

Say I have the following identity:

$$\sin40^\circ+\sin20^\circ+\cos30^\circ = 2\cos20^\circ\cos10^\circ$$

I worked on the left-hand side using the first prosthaphaeresis formula.

$$2\sin30^\circ\cos20^\circ + \cos30^\circ = \cos20^\circ+\cos30^\circ$$

Though, I don't know where to go from here. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your computations:
$$
\sin\alpha+\sin\beta=2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}
$$
and
$$
2\cos\alpha\cos\beta=\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)
$$

Therefore, the left-hand side becomes
$$
2\sin30^\circ\cos10^\circ+\cos30^\circ
$$
and the right-hand side becomes
$$
\cos30^\circ+\cos10^\circ
$$
so the identity to be verified is
$$
2\sin30^\circ\cos10^\circ=\cos10^\circ
$$
and, since $\sin30^\circ=1/2$, we're done

Comment: @Cesare I added the formula

Comment: Thank you for your help! This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

We can start by the conversion $$cos\theta=sin(90-\theta),$$

Converting the LHS to $$sin20+sin40+sin60$$ as you can see, the angles are in an arithmetic progression, and by the well known formula:

$$sina+sin(a+d)+sin(a+2d)+....+sin(a+(n-1)d)=\frac{sin(\frac{nd}{2})}{sin(\frac{d}{2})}sin(a+(n-1)\frac{d}{2})$$ 
Makes the LHS = $$\frac{sin30}{sin10}.sin40$$
Put $sin(30)$=1/2 and open $sin(40)=2sin(20)cos(20)$ and again open $sin(20)$ to get the required expression.